# Who is this Star Wars character?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

I was searching for Star Wars artwork when I found [this](http://designtaxi.com/news/366912/Colorful-Minimalist-Flat-Design-Icons-Of-Famous-Star-Wars-Characters/). Being minimalist artwork, it's hard to tell who some of the characters are since they lack detail. I've been able to guess *most* of the characters (but I could be wrong about some of them) but I have no idea who the middle one is.

[image]

The middle character looks like the Inquisitor from *Star Wars: Rebels*

[image]

Or it could be a Death Star Trooper

[image]

---

Comment: For it to be a Death Star trooper, the artist would have to assume that we'd recognize an unimportant generic character set we only see for a few seconds.

Comment: It must be a well known character, presumably from the OT.  The only such character you haven't identified is Palpatine.  Think about it from the other side:  If that square wasn't in the picture, would you think "Where is the *Rebels* character that almost no one has heard of?"  or "Why isn't there one of the Death Star doofuses in the silly bowl helmets?"  I wouldn't.  I would think "WHERE THE HELL IS THE MAIN ANTAGONIST OF THE TRILOGY?"

Comment: Also, when did *Rebels* come out?  That link is over a year old, so the image is at least that old.  If *Rebels* is younger than the picture, it can't be a *Rebels* character.

Comment: @WadCheber 1) thank you, 2) let's say I couldn't ID *any* of the characters in a certain picture, would it be bad to ask who they are on SF.SE? 3) how does one pronounce you username?

Comment: @Wad Cheber - Good point, Rebels came out in October 2014, and if you go to the artist's website [here](https://www.behance.net/creativeflip) and click "Star Wars - Long Shadow Flat Design Icons" you can see the image was published in June 2014.

Comment: @redcaio - 2.  People might think you were crazy for not knowing what Vader, R2, C-3PO, etc, look like (ask Rand al'Thor about the donkey he has to ride because he hasn't seen SW), but it would certainly be on topic and appropriate for the site.  3.  It's a spoonerism of my real name, and rhymes with my real name.

Comment: Let's say it rhymes with "Mad Clever", if the "v" in "clever" was a "b".

Comment: Looks like [Asajj Ventress](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/f/f8/Ventress_TDS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090409154311)

Comment: It's clearly meant to be the Emperor, though he appears to be fashionally inspired by Egyptian pharaohs in this particular depiction, for whatever reason…

Answer (score 65, accepted):

All of them look right to me.

The one you can't identify is...

## Darth Sidious

[image]

(Aka Emperor Palpatine)

Comment: Really? Looks more like the [1st Inquisitor](http://orig07.deviantart.net/d553/f/2014/246/c/3/cloaked_inquisitor__star_wars_rebels_fan_art__by_brian_snook-d7xoxuc.jpg), lol. I would've done Sidious very differently (were I the artist).

Comment: @RedCaio - Notice that all the others are from the original trilogy, not a single prequel or animated spinoff character in the bunch, so that should increase the likelihood that character is too to give the whole thing more of a unified theme (and going with that, I would just call him The Emperor if you want to add labels--Sidious is never used in the original trilogy). Plus the hood that widens towards the bottom matches the Emperor, not the Inquisitor, and it's lacking the red stripes which are distinctive enough that if the artist wanted to do the Inquisitor they'd probably be there.

Comment: This would be the most likely answer. All the characters portrayed are from the original trilogy and the Emperor is the only "named" character who fits the minimalist art work.

Comment: as an aside the etymological roots (if in Latin) mean he is emperor Feely-Moths (Palpa - feel; Tine - Moths (from tinea - moth)), could also be MothTongue, MothTaster, MothStroker.  May well be from another language thou, as it originates a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away . . .

Answer (score 29):

To supplement N Soong's answer, some arguments in favor of it being Palpatine:

1. Every other character is from the original trilogy.  Why would there be a single exception to that rule?
2. If that part of the image wasn't there, would you say "Where's the Inquisitor who wasn't even in the same movie series as these other characters?"  No.  Would you think "Why didn't the artist draw one of the random Death Star personnel in funny bowl helmets who are only onscreen for a few seconds?"  No.  But you would probably say "Why the hell didn't the artist include the main antagonist of the franchise to date?"  That antagonist is Palpatine.
3. These are the main players in the original trilogy - the iconic figures whose images are engraved in the memories of billions of people.   Bowl-head Death Star guys and the Inquisitor are insignificant and almost unknown.
4. This picture was [posted to the artist's website](https://www.behance.net/creativeflip) in June, 2014.  It is presumably somewhat older than that.  *[Star Wars: Rebels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels)* premiered more than 4 months later, so the artist couldn't have known who or what the Inquisitor was, let alone what that character would look like.

Taken together, it is clear that the only character who would be a logical choice, and who actually looks like this picture, is Palpatine.